# Move window to top from current position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collapse button for text viewing which works fine expect jQuery animate function.

When I click on a button, window moves to the bottom and then moves to the top. 
If I remove one line (which hides part of the text) everything works fine (without moving to the bottom).

Any ideas how to make it work without moving to the bottom first?

Source code:

```
$('.collapse_btn').click(function() {
    $('.r1').css({'max-height':r1h_nh});
    $(this).hide();
    $('.expand_btn').show();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: I think [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) will make it better to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your window is scrolled to bottom because element `.collapse_btn` disappeas. So what if you do the hide/show operation **after** you scroll window to top using [jQuery.animate callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

```
   $('.collapse_btn').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow', 'swing', function(){
//scrollTop is done, now perform what you need, it won't be visible anyway
          $('.r1').css({'max-height':r1h_nh});
             $('.collapse_btn').hide();
             $('.expand_btn').show();
          });
        });
```